# Integer solution $(x,y,z)$ to $xyz=24$

Tags: permutations

> Find the total number of integer solutions $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{Z}$ of the equation $xyz=24$.

I have tried $xyz = 2^3 \cdot 3$

**My Process:**

Factor $x$, $y$, and $z$ as
$$
\begin{cases}
x = 2^{x_1} \cdot 3^{y_1}\\
y = 2^{x_2} \cdot 3^{y_2}\\
z = 2^{x_3} \cdot 3^{y_3}
\end{cases}
$$

Now $2^{x_1+x_2+x_3} \cdot 3^{y_1+y_2+y_3} = 2^3 \cdot 3$, so

$$
\begin{cases}
x_1+x_2+x_3 = 3\\
y_1+y_2+y_3 = 1
\end{cases}
$$

where $x_1,x_2,x_3,y_1,y_2,y_3\geq 0$. Thus the number of solutions for the first is $\binom{5}{2}=10$ and second is $\binom{3}{2}=3$. This gives a total number of positive solutions of $10 \cdot 3 = 30$

How can I calculate the total number of solutions? Is this process correct?

Comment: The election of auxiliary variables isn't precisely stellar... too easy to get lost among $x$, $x_i$ and so on jumbled together.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your logic is correct for positive solutions. Now you need the sign pattern to be $+++,+--,-+-,--+$, four possibilities, so multiply by four.

Comment: Thanks Ross Millikan Got it

Comment: @RossMillikan
Can you help me with how OP got $5C2$ solutions for first or the one for second? It's not that I am not convinced but I am trying to learn.

Comment: @user1709828:  He was finding the number of [compositions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28number_theory%29) of 5 into 3 parts and of 3 into 3 parts.  How to compute these is shown in the Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this looks right for finding the number of positive integer solutions.

Since you originally asked for *all* integer solutions, you'll also have to take into account the signs of the factors. There are $\binom{3}{0} + \binom{3}{2} = 4$ ways of adding zero or two minus signs, for a total of 120 integer solutions.